# Magento 2.2.4 - Breadcrumbs do not show on product pages when default navigation is not present

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

I have a Megamenu extension installed replacing the default navigation menu. This however when added breaks breadcrumbs on product pages.

I have debugged by also removing both navigation and this also breaks the navigation so I believe the issue lies with default navigation being required somehow for breadcrumbs to work now. I could of sworn however this was working on 2.2.4 earlier this week as had below issue:

[Issue with Magento 2.2.4 - quotation mark in product name break product pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224587/issue-with-magento-2-2-4-quotation-mark-in-product-name-break-product-pages)

This i resolved however am sure did not break breadcrumbs as the time. Reverting does not fix breadcrumbs either.

How do breadcrumbs work now? They seem to load asynchronously and not sure they did before.

From what i can tell the below function in breadcrumbs.js renders the breadcrumbs:

```
    _render: function () {
        var html,
            crumbs = breadcrumbList,
            template = mageTemplate(tpl);

        this._decorate(crumbs);

        html = template({
            'breadcrumbs': crumbs
        });

        if (html.length) {
            $(this.element).html(html);
        }
    },
```

However im not sure how it grabs the data for the `html` variable and why it breaks when i remove the default navigation.

Comment: are u fixed this issue?

Comment: I just adapted an earlier plugin i made to also fix this. This is listed in my answer.

Comment: this is correct one  https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

Comment: Still i can't get the breadcrumbs in view page? Any idea about that?

Comment: Yeah that is the one, that is quite odd. When did this start happening?

Comment: I'm trying to add product type for breadcrumbs.so I'm using aroundGetBreadcrumbPath(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $subject, callable $proceed).Its not working...

Comment: I can able to get the breadcrumbs path using  github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs.Its working fine....But i need to add type with breadcrumbs....Can u guide me...I'm spend lot of time in this section

Comment: Ok well i think you need to ask a question which is clear on what you want and ill help if i can just a bit unsure what you mean at the moment.

Comment: Ok....Thanks....Why we can add getCrumb() function in this block after upgrade?

Comment: Why the default breadcrumb was not working?

Comment: The getCrumb function in my module creates an array of the breadcrumb path. This array includes the labels, urls ect. I'm not entirely sure it seems to be that breadcrumbs were improved to maybe not get cached as this was leading to the incorrect breadcrumbs after full page cache. The way in which it works now however seems to rely on the default navigation which i do not use sometimes. I'm not sure what needs to be added to custom navigation however to get it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80594/discussion-between-mano-m-and-harri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the braedcrumbs are now heavily reliant on the default navigation and so all custom menus may need to adapt to fix this. I think this was an attempt to fix caching of incorrect breadcrumbs.

Instead of fixing my megamenu and because the default breadcrumbs are still poor for me as when searching they never show for a product i have ripped the default breadcrumbs and replaced with my own.

```
public function getCrumbs()
{
    $evercrumbs = array();

    $evercrumbs[] = array(
        'label' => 'Home',
        'title' => 'Go to Home Page',
        'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
    );

    $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
    $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

    $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
    $categoryCollection->clear();
    $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
    $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
    $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
    foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
        $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => $category->getName(),
            'title' => $category->getName(),
            'link' => $category->getUrl()
        );
    }

    $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => $product->getName(),
            'title' => $product->getName(),
            'link' => ''
        );

    return $evercrumbs;
}
```

And then replaced default breadcrumbs with my own:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Harrigo\EverCrumbs\Block\Evercrumbs" name="evercrumbs" as="evercrumbs" template="Harrigo_EverCrumbs::evercrumbs.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the template for the block:

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getCrumbs(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have updated my EverCrumbs module if you wish to simply install and use this or look over the full code used:

> https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

Comment: I have installed your extension, but breadcrumb is not correct shows when product added in multiple categories.

Comment: Yeah that is my main issue. It would be wrong on normal magento although also depending on which page it was originally cached on so is still an improvement.

Comment: Hi @harri can u please help me on this issue ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257932/magento-2-breadcrumbs-issue-on-product-view-page/257937?noredirect=1#comment363428_257937

Comment: @NagarajuKasa This looks like a similar problem mentioned in this question here. As stated i think in my question the breadcrumbs may potentially being cached and if visited from search or directly no category is present weather or not you later visit from a category these old crumbs will get stuck in FPC. Have you tried flushing cache and visiting from category to see if they work then. Do the reverse and the breadcrumbs may not work. If so try my module and all should work,

Comment: Actually i think my question is different buy my answer should solve your issue none the less. I think i did have a question once where i solve your issue and this question updated my module to work with 2.2.5 or 2.2.6 as breadcrumbs relied on having default nav

Answer (score 19):

With help of some posts on stackexchange, I found out this solution, This approach does not require you to override with di.xml

**YOUR_THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content.top">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Create a module with the following block:

**Vendor/Module/Block/Breadcrumbs.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Breadcrumbs extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs
{
    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $catalogData, Registry $registry, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve HTML title value separator (with space)
     *
     * @param null|string|bool|int|Store $store
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitleSeparator($store = null)
    {
        $separator = (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/seo/title_separator', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        return ' ' . $separator . ' ';
    }
    
    public function getCrumbs() {
        return $this->_crumbs;
    }

    /**
     * Preparing layout
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout() {

        $title = [];
        if ($breadcrumbsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                    'home', [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
                    ]
            );
            $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
            $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

            if ($product && count($path) == 1) {
                $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
                $categoryCollection->clear();
                $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
                $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
                $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();

                foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
                    $catbreadcrumb = array("label" => $category->getName(), "link" => $category->getUrl());
                    $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb("category" . $category->getId(), $catbreadcrumb);
                    $title[] = $category->getName();
                }
                //add current product to breadcrumb
                $prodbreadcrumb = array("label" => $product->getName(), "link" => "");
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb("product" . $product->getId(), $prodbreadcrumb);
                $title[] = $product->getName();
            } else {
                foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
                    $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
                    $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
                }
            }
            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }
        $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
        foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
        }
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**YOUR_THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\breadcrumbs.phtml**

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>

            <?php
                $label = $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']);
                $link = $block->escapeUrl($crumbInfo['link']);
            ?>

            <li class="item <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbName) ?>">
            <?php if ($link) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $link ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?= $label ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                    <strong><?= $label ?></strong>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= $label ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: your solution is working perfectly:)

Comment: Only thing missing here is ordering by level and also position

Comment: Hi @nuwaus could u please look into my issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257932/magento-2-breadcrumbs-issue-on-product-view-page/257937?noredirect=1#comment363428_257937

Comment: Hi nuwaus i have tried u r answer but getting "Invalid template file: 'html/breadcrumbs.phtml' can u please suggest  where i need to add breadcrumbs.phtml?

Comment: @Nagaraju Kasa, In magento breadcrumbs.phtml is at this location : vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html

If you want to override it, then you have to put it in your theme folder and path will be as below : Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: You don't have to replace the original template, it also works perfectly fine.

Comment: With a couple of adjustments to suit my needs, this worked lovely on 2.4.3-pl
Thanks for posting your hard work bud - you're a star

Answer (score 3):

**In design/frontend/VendorTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="VendorName\Breadcrumbs\Block\CatalogBreadcrumbs" name="product.view.breadcrumbs" template="VendorName_Breadcrumbs::breadcrumbs.phtml" />       
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**In app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml:**

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getBreadcrumb(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
                <li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">
                    <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**In Block/CatalogBreadcrumbs.php:**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Breadcrumbs\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CatalogBreadcrumbs extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs
{

    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;
    protected $path = array();

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $catalogData, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getTitleSeparator($store = null)
    {
        $separator = (string) $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/seo/title_separator', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        return ' ' . $separator . ' ';
    }

    public function getBreadcrumb()
    {
        $this->addCrumb(
                'home', [
            'label' => __('Home'),
            'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
            'link' => $this->getBaseUrl()
                ]
        );
        foreach ((array) $this->path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $this->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
        }
        return $this->getCrumbs();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
        $title = [];
        foreach ((array) $this->path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
        }
        return $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
        //return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCrumbs()
    {
        return $this->_crumbs;
    }

    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

}
```

If you got it, let me know.

Comment: it works fine in 2.3.5 too.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you it work for me !
juste some improvement to get the key in phtml like default breadcrumb

```
public function getCrumbs()
{
    $evercrumbs = array();

    $evercrumbs[] = array(
        'label' => 'Home',
        'title' => 'Go to Home Page',
        'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(),
        'key' => 'home'
    );

    $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
    $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
    $categoryCollection->clear();
    $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
    $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
    $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
    foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
        $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => $category->getName(),
            'title' => $category->getName(),
            'link' => $category->getUrl(),
            'key' => $category->getUrlKey()
        );
    }


    $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => $product->getName(),
            'title' => $product->getName(),
            'link' => '',
            'key' => $product->getUrlKey()
        );

    return $evercrumbs;
}
```

and in phtml file replace 
`<li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">`

by 
`<li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['key'] ?>">`

I also have error with the file module.xml in your github so i change it to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Harrigo_EverCrumbs" active="true" setup_version="1.0.1"/>
```

Comment: I will look after and update the module thanks.

Comment: Thats a wiered module.xml however what was going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Know that since the update the product page has its own breadcrumbs :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

I have made a module to fix this:

https://github.com/CompactCodeEU/FixProductBreadcrumbs

Composer Install Instructions

```
composer config repositories.compact-code-fix-product-breadcrumbs git git@github.com:CompactCodeEU/FixProductBreadcrumbs.git

composer require "compactcode/fixproductbreadcrumbs:dev-master"

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: I have made a module for those who are intrested

Comment: https://github.com/CompactCodeEU/FixProductBreadcrumbs

Comment: Not working as expected.wrong breadscrumb generated.

Comment: Enlighten me . What is not working

Comment: code is working but displaying wrong breadcrumbs on product detail page.

Comment: Still i need more details. What is wrong? What do you get and what do your expect it to return?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution, approved by Magento team. Because if you use approaches with block rewrites or plugins and you have some extensions that use Breadcrumbs block or Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View.php, you'll have problems.
So, you have to customize just app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js.
So, here are full code:

```
    /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/model/breadcrumb-list'
], function ($, breadcrumbList) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.breadcrumbs', widget, {
            options: {
                categoryUrlSuffix: '',
                useCategoryPathInUrl: false,
                product: '',
                menuContainer: '[data-action="navigation"] > ul'
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            _render: function () {
                this._appendCatalogCrumbs();
                this._super();
            },

            /**
             * Append category and product crumbs.
             *
             * @private
             */
            _appendCatalogCrumbs: function () {
                var categoryCrumbs = this._resolveCategoryCrumbs();

                categoryCrumbs.forEach(function (crumbInfo) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(crumbInfo);
                });

                if (this.options.product) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(this._getProductCrumb());
                }
            },

            /**
             * Resolve categories crumbs.
             *
             * @return Array
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryCrumbs: function () {
                var menuItem = this._resolveCategoryMenuItem(),
                    categoryCrumbs = [];

                if (menuItem !== null && menuItem.length) {
                    categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));

                    while ((menuItem = this._getParentMenuItem(menuItem)) !== null) {
                        categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));
                    }
                }

                return categoryCrumbs;
            },

            /**
             * Returns crumb data.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {

                return {
                    'name': 'category',
                    'label': menuItem.text(),
                    'link': menuItem.attr('href'),
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Returns product crumb.
             *
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getProductCrumb: function () {
                return {
                    'name': 'product',
                    'label': this.options.product,
                    'link': '',
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Find parent menu item for current.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _getParentMenuItem: function (menuItem) {
                var classes,
                    classNav,
                    parentClass,
                    parentMenuItem = null;

                if (!menuItem) {
                    return null;
                }

                classes = menuItem.parent().attr('class');
                classNav = classes.match(/(nav\-)[0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)+/gi);

                if (classNav) {
                    classNav = classNav[0];
                    parentClass = classNav.substr(0, classNav.lastIndexOf('-'));

                    if (parentClass.lastIndexOf('-') !== -1) {
                        parentMenuItem = $(this.options.menuContainer).find('.' + parentClass + ' > a');
                        parentMenuItem = parentMenuItem.length ? parentMenuItem : null;
                    }
                }

                return parentMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category menu item.
             *
             * Tries to resolve category from url or from referrer as fallback and
             * find menu item from navigation menu by category url.
             *
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryMenuItem: function () {
                var categoryUrl = this._resolveCategoryUrl(),
                    menu = $(this.options.menuContainer),
                    categoryMenuItem = null;

                if (categoryUrl && menu.length) {
                    categoryMenuItem = menu.find('a[href="' + categoryUrl + '"]');
                }

                return categoryMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category url.
             *
             * @return {String}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryUrl: function () {
                var categoryUrl;

                if (this.options.useCategoryPathInUrl) {
                    // In case category path is used in product url - resolve category url from current url.
                    categoryUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                    categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substring(0, categoryUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) +
                        this.options.categoryUrlSuffix;
                } else {
                    // In other case - try to resolve it from referrer (without parameters).
                    categoryUrl = document.referrer;

                    if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                    }
                }

                return categoryUrl;
            }
        });

        return $.mage.breadcrumbs;
    };
});
```

And here is a link to merge request: [ENGCOM-1707](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/99d33d3e803258d63dd55a9eb2c87e21aa70d8d4)

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the **_resolveCategoryMenuItem** return null. Can you please share a better solution for this.

Comment: JS for breadcrumbing is probably the stupidest idea magento devs ever had.

Answer (score 0):

In my instance, I created a plugin to update the **Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs::getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped()** function return value since I only needed to update the default widget options in this js file: **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js**

The main issue was the default menu selectors (**categoryItemSelector** and **menuContainer**) did not match the current menu structure. Another route would be to fix the new menu structure and update the classes to match the default values. You could always do a js file override or mixin as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can overwrite di.xml file, it can be done with following code:

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data"
                type="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data"/>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
{
    public function getBreadcrumbPath()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');

        $path = [];
        $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
        $categoryCollection->clear();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'path',
                ['like' => "1/".$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()."/%"]
            );
        $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
        $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();

        foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
            $path['category'.$category->getId()] = ["label" => $category->getName(), "link" => $category->getUrl()];
        }

        if ($product) {
            $path['product'] = ["label" => $product->getName(), "link" => ""];
        }
        $this->_categoryPath = $path;

        return $this->_categoryPath;
    }
}
```