# Magento 2: Include Product url in custom js file

Tags: magento2, javascript

How to include **product url** in `Custom js` file,

In Magento2.

I am using below code in template file:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_product_url= $_product->getProductUrl();
echo $_product_url;
```

How to use it in js file

Comment: Can you explain little bit more? where you want to add product url?

Comment: Do you need product url in custom js file from product detail page ?

Comment: Yes, from product detail page

Comment: please find the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code on product page

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_url" id="product_url" value="<?php echo  $_product_url ?>" />
```

Then get this hidden filed value in your custom javascript as follow

```
var productUrl = document.getElementById('product_url').value;
```

Please let me know still if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks @user55548 is that above code will work in custom.js file

Comment: my file is not template file

Comment: Put hidden field code you any phtml file which is use on product detail page. eg. put code in addtocart.phtml or gallery.phtml. Just make sure that code should be after crate product object. Then you can fetch value in javascript of that hidden filed.

Comment: Put your code in hidden filed like
<input type="hidden" name="product_url" id="product_url" value="<?php echo  $_product_url ?>" /> In your custom js file var productUrl = document.getElementById('product_url').value

Comment: Thanks a lot @user55548 its working fine.

Comment: Hi @user55548 i want little help ragarding facebook sharing to condtions to only me and public using jquery

Comment: You can create new question for that and let me know that question url. I will let you know if i know answer. this way you can get answer from other also.

Comment: please find the below question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264839/how-to-check-facebook-share-condtions-based-of-public-or-only-me-using-jquery-ma