# Magento 2 : Show all categories of a product

Tags: magento2, product, category-products, product-page, breadcrumbs

Actual state:
My products are in several categories.
Thus, when I call a product from an over category or by searching out, only the following is displayed in the breadcrumb:

"Start > ProductName " Although the product is in: "Start > Category1
Category2 > ProductName"
And
"Start > Category3 > Category4 > ProductName" is contained.

Target state:
I would like to display all categories of the respective product on the product page.
It doesn't matter if it's breadcrumb or in the left sidebar.

I hope you can help me. :)

Current System:
Ubuntu 18.04
MariaDB
Magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

To get breadcrumb output like this you can follow below links. It will work according to your requirement.

[Magento 2.2.4 - Breadcrumbs do not show on product pages when default navigation is not present](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/magento-2-2-4-breadcrumbs-do-not-show-on-product-pages-when-default-navigation)

https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the super fast answer.
I installed the module and it works so far, with one exception.
It always shows the last category and not all.
Can you help me with that too? :)