# Magento 2 - Breadcrumbs not showing full path

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs, magento2.3.4

My breadcrumbs are only showing like `Home > Productname`

instead of `Home > Category -> Subcategory -> Productname`

Is there a way to fix this? I tried with the fresh mangento luma theme, to show that it is not a fault of my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Breadcrumbs-in-Magento-2/m-p/101790/highlight/true#M5277).

> When you land on product page from category page then breadcrumb will
>   be
>
> **Home -> Product Category -> Product Name**
>
> But when you click on product other then category listing page then
>   breadcrumb will be
>
> **Home  -> Product Name**
>
> This is not a issue that how magento work.

I wonder if you can change it so that it always shows the category, this would be much better.

**EDIT**: Solution for full breadcrumbs path can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/233023/66769).