# Magento 2 - Breadcrumbs not showing full path

Tags: magento2, extensions, breadcrumbs, magento2-enterprise, megamenu

Magento version : 2.4.5-p1 (same issue in version 2.4.3)

Breadcrumbs show only **`Home > Product name`** instead of **`Home > Category > Sub category > Product name`**.
I already checked [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/magento-2-2-4-breadcrumbs-do-not-show-on-product-pages-when-default-navigation/233023#233023) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305710/magento-2-breadcrumbs-not-showing-full-path) questions but since there is a significant version difference I couldn't fix the issue.

I have installed **Rootways Megamenu** module, and when I disable it the breadcrumb shows the full path without any issue. Also tried changing Megamenu settings, but not fixed.

Have anyone experienced this issue? And are there any fixes without uninstalling the Megamenu module?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.6 / Theme porto extension Mega Menu.

I have the same problem on my magento 2.4.6. Have you found a fix?