# Magento 2.4 Display Breadcrumbs in Product View Page

Tags: magento2

I am currently having difficulties displaying the correct breadcrumbs in my product view page in Magento 2.4.

What I'm currently seeing if I am in a product that is e.g. **Cat 1 > Sub 1 > Product** is:

**Home > Productname**

Here some details:

Block being used: /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml

Content:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs $block */
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs $viewModel */
    $viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
    ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
    <?php
    $widget = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonDecode($viewModel->getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped());
    $widgetOptions = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($widget['breadcrumbs']);
    ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            ".breadcrumbs": {
                "breadcrumbs": <?= /* @noEscape */ $widgetOptions ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Ideally this should display as: **Home > Cat > Sub 1**

I would not want to use any additional plugin or extension, so I am wondering if there is any method to have this adjusted quickly? Thank you

Comment: You have to use a custom Extension, Chekout this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/magento-2-2-4-breadcrumbs-do-not-show-on-product-pages-when-default-navigation/233023#233023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to add block in your module

> Path: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Crumbblock.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Crumbblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        Data $catalogData, 
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData; 
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCrumbs()
    {
        $evercrumbs = array();
        
        $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'title' => 'Go to Home Page',
            'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
        );

        $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
        $categoryCollection->clear();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
        $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
        $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
        foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
            $evercrumbs[] = array(
                'label' => $category->getName(),
                'title' => $category->getName(),
                'link' => $category->getUrl()
            );
        }
    
        
        $evercrumbs[] = array(
                'label' => $product->getName(),
                'title' => $product->getName(),
                'link' => ''
            );
                
        return $evercrumbs;
    }
}
```

After that add layout file `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module

> Path should be:
> `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Crumbblock" name="crumbs" as="crumbs" template="Vendor_Module::crumbs.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After that Add phtml file in your module

> Path Should be like:
> `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\crumbs.phtml`

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getCrumbs(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php
            foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
                <li class="item <?php echo $crumbName == 0 ? "home" : ""; ?>">
                    <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php
            endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this today

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Fot those of you who are struggling with showing the breadcrumbs of a product within magento ^2.4: please note that regenerating the categories with the bin/magento regenerate:category:tree might also help. It did in my case at least.

Comment: It seems that this has been removed at least in Magento 2.4.3

Comment: With my installation 2.4.3-p1  it's still present